# How do I sort a list by specific characters within each element?

Tags: python, list, function, sorting

I have been asked to define a function that sorts a list based on file extension..

I understand sorting, but I don't understand how to start the sort from the "." character.

I want the following result:

```
>>> extsort(['a.c', 'a.py', 'b.py', 'bar.txt', 'foo.txt', 'x.c'])
['a.c', 'x.c', 'a.py', 'b.py', 'bar.txt', 'foo.txt']
```

Comment: read up on the `key` parameter

Comment: look at sort and supplying a lambda function that parses and reverses the file name and extension so starting with file.ext return ext.file in the lambda.  this works with the item from John Coleman.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass key function as a parameter for [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> l = ['a.c', 'a.py', 'b.py', 'bar.txt', 'foo.txt', 'x.c']
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: splitext('.')[1])
['a.c', 'a.py', 'b.py', 'bar.txt', 'foo.txt', 'x.c']
```

If you need the files to with same extension to be sorted by their name you can change key function to reverse the split result:

```
>>> l = ['x.c', 'a.py', 'b.py', 'bar.txt', 'foo.txt', 'a.c']
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: splitext(x)[::-1])
['a.c', 'x.c', 'a.py', 'b.py', 'bar.txt', 'foo.txt']
```

Comment: for `l = ['x.c', 'a.py', 'b.py', 'bar.txt', 'foo.txt', 'a.c']`, i think your solution is not right. the output is `['x.c', 'a.c', 'a.py', 'b.py', 'bar.txt', 'foo.txt']`, i think thr author want `['a.c', 'x.c', 'a.py', 'b.py', 'bar.txt', 'foo.txt']`.

Comment: ok I see but one question..What is the [1] specifying at the end of the lambda function?

Comment: @BlackMamba Well, possibly.  The OP did not specify if the values *within* a given extension must be sorted.

Comment: @BlackMamba How so? I got result `['x.c', 'a.c', 'a.py', 'b.py', 'bar.txt', 'foo.txt']` where the files are sorted by extension. The question didn't specify on how the files with same extension should be sorted so they are treated the same.

Comment: @niemmi If you want to satisfy all the haters, you could use `lambda x: (x.rsplit('.', 1)[1], x)`

Comment: @Este Added explanation to the answer

Comment: Nvm.. It's specifying the 1st character after the "." character.. Thanks soo much!

Comment: @niemmi You could also use `lambda x: x.rsplit('.', 1)[::-1]`, which is a bit more readable.

Comment: @SethMMorton Thanks, I think `x.rsplit('.', 1)[::-1]` is better

Comment: @niemmi Yup, I edited my comment at the same instant you edited the answer.

Comment: Downside to this, even after edits, is that it doesn't handle files without extensions consistently. It sorts the extensions of files with extensions against the full name of files without extensions, instead of having files without extensions sort together (if you have `eggs`, `foo.py` and `spam`, it's comparing `eggs`, `py` and `spam`). This is why `os.path.splitext` exists, to consistently get two elements even when there is no file extension, and to do so in a consistent organization (`str.rpartition` gets a consistent three elements, but sadly, not in the order you need them to be in).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for pointing this out, I've edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 3):

For a solution that works even if some of the files don't have extensions (and is somewhat more self-documenting), use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) as part of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)'s `key` function. When there is no file extension, it will treat the extension as the empty string, `''`, sorting it before all other extensions:

```
>>> l = ['b.py', 'a.c', 'a.py', 'bar.txt', 'foo.txt', 'x.c', 'foo']
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[1])
['foo', 'a.c', 'x.c', 'b.py', 'a.py', 'bar.txt', 'foo.txt']
```

Note that `b.py` sorted before `a.py` here, because it appeared first in the input, and the sort only keyed on the file extension. To make it sort by extension, then full name, key on a tuple of the extension followed by the non-extension name (easily done by slicing `os.path.splitext`'s return value using `[::-1]` which reverses the order of the elements returned), so `a.py` precedes `b.py` regardless of where they appeared in the input:

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[::-1])
['foo', 'a.c', 'x.c', 'a.py', 'b.py', 'bar.txt', 'foo.txt']
```